# How to define Transaction Timeout during debugging application

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, timeout, transactionscope

I am testing whether option from app.config listed below Is applied to all transactions in the application.

```
<system.transactions>
   <defaultSettings timeout="00:05:00" />
</system.transactions>
```

Transaction are defined using transaction scope in following way

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
```

Is it possible to find out what timeout has transaction created by transaction scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using transactionoptions.timeout, see:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/250b40b9-0838-4142-a8ff-d9d26690083b

**EDIT**

Transaction scope does not have any public properties, so you will not be able to get any information. You only have access to the timeout through the constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: Well the article say only how to SET timeout. Make sure that maxTimeOut configuration option does not override it. I want to check whether transaction has appropriate time out or not. I.E. I need to GET transaction timeout.